# Why doesnt an aws api-gateway pass the origin header to my lambda when accessed over http1.1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-headers

This issue does not happen when using http2, it seems specific to http1.1.

Given an aws nodejs 18 lambda with the following code

```
export const healthHandler = async (event) => {
    return {
        body: `ok! origin: '${event.headers['origin']}'`
    }
}
```

deployed into an aws api-gateway using serverless

```
service: gateway-cors
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: test
  runtime: nodejs18.x
functions:
  health:
    handler: index.healthHandler
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: health/{any+}
          cors: true
```

If make a webrequest over http2, i get

```
curl https://<id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/health/test -H "Origin: https://test.com" --http2
    ok! origin: 'https://test.com'
```

but if i make it over http1.1 i instead get

```
curl https://<id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/health/test -H "Origin: https://test.com" --http1.1
    ok! origin: 'undefined'
```

Repo with full repro [available here](https://github.com/Zazcallabah/gateway-cors/blob/main/serverless.yml)

Does anyone know why aws api gateway does not pass on the origin header over http1.1, and is there a way I can -make- it pass on the origin header?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is because the gateway rewrites the header to follow http2 header specs when you use http2. For http1.1 the header is still supplied, but it is using its original name 'Origin' with capital O.

changing the return to `'${event.headers['origin'] ?? event.headers['Origin']}'` clarifies the situation.